# Guice inject context instance that is created upon each request

Tags: java, dependency-injection, request, guice

Is there a way to have [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki) to bind to a certain type of instance that is created upon new request?

Pseudocode using with `ThreadLocal`:

```
// upon request incoming, creating the context
Context context = new Context(request, response);
// save to threadlocal so later on we can get it from
// a provider
Context.setThreadLocal(context);
...

// in the AppModule.java file
modules.add(new AbstractModule() {
    @Override   
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Context.class).toProvider(new Provider<Context>() {
            @Override public Context get() {return Context.getThreadLocal();}
        });
    }
});
...

// in another source file
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(modules);
// suppose Foo has a context property and injector shall
// inject the current context to foo instance
Foo foo = injector.getInstance(Foo.class);
```

Can I implement this behavior without a `ThreadLocal`?

Answer (score 2):

Guice has the concept of [Scopes](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes). It sounds like you're looking for something bound with the [`@RequestScoped`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/) annotation. This will bind an instance that persists for the life of the request, and will inject a new object for the next request.

There is also [`@SessionScoped`](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/servlet/SessionScoped.html) for when you want the object to persist for an entire session.

[You can read up on their examples here](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ServletModule), which includes [some language on how to use `@RequestScoped`](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ServletModule#using-requestscope).

Comment: I checked the implementation of SessionScope and RequestScope, looks like they are also using `ThreadLocal`